# Can session cookies used for sending many requests to a webserver

Tags: http, httpclient, session-cookies, ddos

I want to know if using session cookies while making HTTPClient requests to a server will help to send many requests per second to a server without causing DOS?

What I mean here is if I sent 100s of HTTPClient requests to a web server in a second it can cause DOS attack, but if i use the session cookie for sending 100's of requests to a web server can that help to prevent DOS.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't know.

It depends what the server *does* with that cookie.